# Android Droid Query How To Recognize Pinching and Zooming

Tags: android, android-gesture, droidquery

I have been using the droidQuery library, which is really great and easy to use. I have used it for custom gesture detection mostly so far. I have a swipeInterceptorView with a swipe listener for detecting swipes, but I also need to detect pinching and zooming in my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library does not currently support pinch zooming, however you can use *droidQuery*'s swiping ability with *Android*'s [ScaleGestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) to get the gesture detection you are seeking.

The following example, should help you:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private float scaleFactor = 1.0f;
    private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    private SwipeInterceptorView view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set main view to the main layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //get a reference to the content view
        view = (SwipeInterceptorView) findViewById(R.id.swipe_view);
        //get the scale gesture detector
        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        //add Swiper
        view.setSwipeListener(new SwipeListener() {
            public void onUpSwipe(View v) {
                //TODO handle up swipe
            }
            public void onRightSwipe(View v) {
                //TODO handle right swipe
            }
            public void onLeftSwipe(View v) {
                //TODO handle left swipe
            }
            public void onDownSwipe(View v) {
                //TODO handle down swipe
            }
        });
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))//this will cause a pinch zoom if two fingers are down
                    return true;
                //if no pinch zoom was handled, the swiping gesture will take over.
                return super.onTouch(v, event);
            }
        });
    }

    //this inner class copied from http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html#scaleGestureDetector
    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 5.0f));

            view.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the pinching and zooming are recognized as swiping

Comment: @superuser Is that instead of zooming, or with it?

Comment: it is instead of zooming.

Comment: I am adding the other stuff to the ontouch to look for zooming on textviews. Is that ok?

Comment: I have noticed that if I pinch or zoom, it is also recognized as a swipe.

Comment: @superuser, you may need to write a full custom `onTouchListener` to get exactly the functionality you seek. If you handle the touch action and action mask, you can determine the current number of fingers touching the screen, and work from there. [droidQuery] and [ScaleGestureDetecor] are meant as conveniences - but there may just be cases where neither suffice.

Comment: ok, thanks! I am writing some custom touch events so that it will never be handled as a swipe if two fingers had been down earlier.